# Make SQL Query With Multiple Date Ranges

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table that keeps track of runs. It has the following columns:

| ID | distance | run_time | run_date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 10 | 01:35:00 | 2023-12-10 |
| 2 | 10 | 01:48:00 | 2023-12-16 |
| 3 | 10 | 01:25:00 | 2023-12-17 |
| 4 | 10 | 01:41:00 | 2023-12-23 |

I want to calculate the average pace per mile (in the format mm:ss) for the current week and the week before it. Here is the query to calculate the average pace for one week:

```
select to_char(sum(run_time) / sum(distance), 'mi:ss')
  from runs
 where run_date between run_date1 and run_date2;
```

Is there a way to do this with just one query and guarantee that the first row of the results corresponds to the first week (the second row corresponds to the second week and so on)?

This is the best that I could come up with:

```
   select to_char(sum(run_time) / sum(distance), 'mi:ss')
      from runs
     where run_date between run_date1 and run_date2 union 
  select to_char(sum(run_time) / sum(distance), 'mi:ss')
      from runs
     where run_date between run_date3 and run_date4
```

Is there a neater way to write this? What if I want to calculate the next 4 weeks? Can we use the in operator to simplify this?

Comment: *"first row of the results corresponds to the first week (the second row corresponds to the second week and so on)"* - is the "week" fixed on monthly basis or based on the earliest runs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`generate_series` function](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-srf.html) makes your problem easy to answer:

In the below example, all the records between 100 days ago to 100 days in the future will be grouped per week, Monday being the first day of the week.
If you want to hardcode a date range instead, simply replace the parameters in `generate_series` by `timestamp`s (or by dates that you cast to `timestamp`).

```sql
WITH Weeks(Day) AS (    
SELECT generate_series(current_timestamp - interval '100 days', current_timestamp + interval '100 days', '1 week')::date 
    + 1 - date_part('dow', current_date)::integer /* Sets Monday as first day of the week */
)
SELECT from_date, to_date, sum(run_time) / sum(distance) AS average_pace
  FROM runs
  JOIN (SELECT DAY, LEAD(Day) OVER (ORDER BY Day) - 1 FROM Weeks) W(from_date, to_date)
  ON run_date BETWEEN from_date and to_date
GROUP BY from_date, to_date
ORDER BY from_date, to_date
```

You can also group your record not according to a Monday-Sunday logic but rather using what your `runs` table contains.

```sql
WITH Weeks(Day) AS (    
SELECT generate_series((SELECT MIN(run_date) FROM runs) , (SELECT MAX(run_date) + 6 FROM runs), '1 week')::date 
)
SELECT from_date, to_date, sum(run_time) / sum(distance) AS average_pace
  FROM runs
  JOIN (SELECT DAY, LEAD(Day) OVER (ORDER BY Day) - 1 FROM Weeks) W(from_date, to_date)
  ON run_date BETWEEN from_date and to_date
GROUP BY from_date, to_date
ORDER BY from_date
```

---

**Additional notes:**

First, in case you did not notice, I subtract 1 to every upper bound of the week. This is because `BETWEEN` includes both the lower and the upper bounds. So with `BETWEEN`, a run taking place the last day of a week would also be considered to take place the first day of the next week.
Instead of `run_date  BETWEEN from_date and to_date - 1`, you could use `run_date >= from_date and run_date < to_date` from the same result.

Also, the part of the query calculating `W` is simply here to grab 2 of the consecutive dates returned by `generate_series`. There is a slightly more compact way of expressing the same idea:

```
SELECT from_date, (from_date - 1 + interval '1 week')::date AS to_date, sum(run_time) / sum(distance) AS average_pace
  FROM runs
  JOIN (
   SELECT generate_series(current_timestamp - interval '100 days', current_timestamp + interval '100 days', '1 week')::date
) W(from_date)
ON run_date BETWEEN from_date and from_date - 1 + interval '1 week'
GROUP BY from_date
ORDER BY from_date
```

However, I find this less convenient: if you want to change the grouping e.g. from 1 to 2 weeks, you must make sure to do it in 3 places (inside `SELECT`, subquery and `ON`) of the query instead of one.

Answer (score 0):

See example with recursive construction calendar table.  In the same way, you can use generate_series instead of recursion. I have cited the use of recursion for completeness of the solution methods.

Needs to  set the `end date` of report  and the `number of weeks` included to report data set.
They can be request parameters.

```
with RECURSIVE report_days as(
 select date_part('ISOYEAR',endDate) yy
  ,date_part('week',endDate) wn
  ,endDate dt
  ,date_add( date_add(endDate,(-weeks ||' week')::interval)
            ,(8-date_part('ISODOW',endDate) ||' days')::interval
    ) first_date
       -- there is parameters endDate and week count
 from ( select '2024-01-14'::date endDate,7::int weeks) myParameters
union all
 select date_part('ISOYEAR',date_add(r.dt,(-1||' day')::interval)::date) yy
  ,date_part('week',date_add(r.dt,(-1||' day')::interval)::date) wn
  ,date_add(r.dt,(-1||' day')::interval)::date dt 
  ,first_date
 from report_days r
 where date_add(r.dt,(-1||' day')::interval)::date>=first_date
)
,allRunsByDate as(
select *
from report_days c
left join runs r on c.dt=r.run_date
)
select yy as year,wn as weekNum
  ,case when sum(run_time)is not null then sum(run_time)/sum(distance) end avg_pace_per_mile
  ,min(dt) from_dt,max(dt) to_dt
  ,count(id) week_qty,sum(distance) week_distance
  ,sum(run_time) week_run_time
from allRunsByDate c
group by yy,wn
order by yy,wn
```

Calculations

```
 date_add( date_add(endDate,(-weeks ||' week')::interval)
            ,(8-date_part('ISODOW',endDate) ||' days')::interval
    ) first_date
```

necessary to take full week near first_date.
For example if day_of_week (DOW) for end_date is wednesday (date_part('ISODOW',endDate)=3)
and, so,
day_of_week for date_add(endDate,(-weeks ||' week')::interval)
is also wednesday,
we add (8-3)=5 days to first_date, so day_of_week of first_date `always is monday`.  There 3+(8-3)=3+5=8->8-8/7*7=1.
So, previous weeks are full weeks, last - my be part of week.

Necessary use `ISOYEAR` key for date_part function. It matters when the beginning of the week does not coincide with the beginning of the year. See also the comments @atmo

If you no need take full weeks, this may be simplified.

For test data

```
insert into runs values
  (1, 10, '01:35:00', '2023-12-10'),
  (2, 10, '01:48:00', '2023-12-16'),
  (3, 10, '01:25:00', '2023-12-17'),
  (4, 10, '01:41:00', '2023-12-23'),
  (5, 20, '02:41:00', '2023-12-23'),
  (6, 15, '02:01:00', '2023-12-25'),
  (7, 15, '02:10:00', '2024-01-05')
  ;
```

request for 7 week result is

| year | weeknum | avg_pace_per_mile | from_dt | to_dt | week_qty | week_distance | week_run_time |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2023 | 48 | null | 2023-11-27 | 2023-12-03 | 0 | null | null |
| 2023 | 49 | 00:09:30 | 2023-12-04 | 2023-12-10 | 1 | 10 | 01:35:00 |
| 2023 | 50 | 00:09:39 | 2023-12-11 | 2023-12-17 | 2 | 20 | 03:13:00 |
| 2023 | 51 | 00:08:44 | 2023-12-18 | 2023-12-24 | 2 | 30 | 04:22:00 |
| 2023 | 52 | 00:08:04 | 2023-12-25 | 2023-12-31 | 1 | 15 | 02:01:00 |
| 2024 | 1 | 00:08:40 | 2024-01-01 | 2024-01-07 | 1 | 15 | 02:10:00 |
| 2024 | 2 | null | 2024-01-08 | 2024-01-14 | 0 | null | null |